Where does ddev import-db of a gz file put the gz file and un-gzipped file?
Presumably this is done in a temporary folder somewhere?
Is this temporary file then deleted after the import is complete?

Please update your question to give more context. Please repeat the question in the text so that the question is understandable. But ddev import-db does not save the .gz file or the unzipped sql file, it imports them into the database. But in some cases it is temporarily ungzipped into .ddev/.importdb, see https://github.com/ddev/ddev/blob/master/pkg/ddevapp/ddevapp.go#L682-L904
